# Rails - Searching/showing available option when creating new instance of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I've got a one to many relationship with one movie per list entry, where a movie can be used in a list entry. My list_entries table has a movie_id and a list_id.
[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa6YJ.png)

I've nested list_entries in lists so I can pass the list_id directly when creating a new instance.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  resources :movies, only: [:new, :index, :create, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update]
  resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  resources :lists, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index, :destroy] do 
  resources :list_entries 
  end

end
```

Right now I can create and destroy list entries but I have to specify the movie id manually.
The UX I want to achieve is for the user to be able to search for movies from themy list_entries/new form but I don't even know where to begin.
The form as it is now:

```
<%= simple_form_for @list_entry, url: list_list_entries_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.input :movie_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn devise-button" %>
<% end %>
```

My list entries controller:

```
class ListEntriesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_list, only: [:index, :create, :show, :new, :destroy]
  def new
    @list_entry = ListEntry.new
  end

  def index
    @list_entries = ListEntry.where(list: @list)
  end

  def show
    @list_entry = ListEntry.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @list_entry = ListEntry.find(params[:id])
    @list_entry.destroy
    redirect_to list_list_entries_path
  end

  def create 
    @list_entry = ListEntry.new(entry_params)
    @list_entry.list_id = params[:list_id]
    if @list_entry.save
    redirect_to list_list_entries_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def find_list
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
  end
  
  def entry_params
    params.require(:list_entry).permit(:comment, :movie_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Louis, would a dropdown suffice? Or do you actually need a search field?

My understanding of your problem is that you would like to offer the user an option to pick a movie. Is that correct?

Comment: HI Tom. I'd like the user to be able to search for a movie and select it. THe site is setup so that users can add movies which means a collection or a dropdown would not be ideal ( the website would have hundreds of movies down the line)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manually specify a movie_id in the form, you can use the simple_form_for association helper:

```
<%= f.input :comment %>
<%= f.association :movie %>
```

I believe it should be labeled based off of the movie title, but if not, you may have to specify a #to_label method in your Movie model.

Alternatively, you could query for the movies in your #new action and use them to do whatever you like in your view:

```
def new
  @list_entry = ListEntry.new
  @movies = Movie.all # or whatever query you think is relevant
end
```

The #collection_select documentation might be useful here:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try ASAP.

Comment: It worked. I'll read the documentation because as of now it is less than ideal ( dropdown is gonna get out of hand when I start seeding). THank you for your help

Comment: I don't believe Rails has any built in helpers for creating a search box. In general, you would want some sort of text box for the search field. You would make an ajax request to the backend and query for movies based on the contents of the request. You would return information regarding the searched movies (you could send the actual HTML to replace on the page or just the titles & ids). From there, you would update the frontend with DOM manipulation. Might be easiest to look up a tutorial, looks like there are plenty of articles on the basics and you can tweak them to your needs.